# How can I push a branch into a separate remote repo?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote

I have a local repo A, with only one branch (`master`) and a remote repo B. Each of those repos has its own history.

I want to push repo A's `master` branch to a new branch called `branch1` in repo B. How can I do that?

Comment: "I want to push the entire **repo** A along with all its history to a **branch** in repo B". That would only (sort of) make sense if repo A consists of only one branch. Is that the case?

Comment: yes @Jubobs . Repo A consists of just master branch.

Comment: What is the name of the branch on repo A, and what should be the name of the new branch on repo B?

Comment: @Jubobs name of the branch on repo A - master (its the master branch) and then create any new branch (say branch1) on repo B and push master from repo A to branch1 on repo B with the chnageset/history intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push your `master` branch on the (local) repo A to a new branch called `branch1` on a (remote) repo B, you need to

1. Make sure that B is listed as a remote repository for repository A at at the correc URL: while within repo A, run

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```

   If you don't see the URL corresponding to repo B in the list, you need to add repo B as a remote for repository A, using

   ```
   git remote add <remote-name> <url>
   ```

   In the following, I'll assume that repository B is listed as a remote for repo A under the remote name `repoB`.
2. Do the push: while within repo A, run

   ```
   git push repoB master:branch1
   ```